# Deleting elements from a list with a given condition

Tags: list-manipulation

```
n = 2
list = Permutations[Range[-n, n], {2}];
list = {{-2, -1}, {-2, 0}, {-2, 1}, {-2, 2}, {-1, -2}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {-1,
   2}, {0, -2}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, -2}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1,
   2}, {2, -2}, {2, -1}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}}
```

How can I delete the cases where `Abs[a+b]>n` and `{a,b}` are elements of the list? In the example above, I would like to delete  `{{-2, -1}, {-1, -2}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}` from the list.

Comment: I think you want to delete  {{-2, -1}, {-1, -2}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select[list, Abs@Total@# <= n &]
```

> {{-2, 0}, {-2, 1}, {-2, 2}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 
>     2}, {0, -2}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, -2}, {1, -1}, {1, 
>     0}, {2, -2}, {2, -1}, {2, 0}}

Answer (score 1):

Also `PatternTest` and `Condition` with `Cases` and `DeleteCases`:

```
Cases[list, _?(Abs@Total@# <= n &)]
DeleteCases[list, _?(Abs@Total@# > n &)]
Cases[list, x_ /; Abs@Total@x <= n]
DeleteCases[list, x_ /; Abs@Total@x > n]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pick[#, UnitStep[n - Abs @ Total @ Transpose @ #], 1] & @ list
```

> {{-2, 0}, {-2, 1}, {-2, 2}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 
>     2}, {0, -2}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, -2}, {1, -1}, {1, 
>     0}, {2, -2}, {2, -1}, {2, 0}}

Timings for `n = 100`:

```
n = 100;
list = Permutations[Range[-n, n], {2}];
Length @ list
```

> 40200

```
functions =  {Pick[#, UnitStep[n - Abs@Total@Transpose@#], 1] &, 
    Select[#, Abs@Total@# <= n &] &, (* J42161217 *)
    Cases[#, _?(Abs@Total@# <= n &)] &, (* Mike Honeychurch *)
    DeleteCases[#, _?(Abs@Total@# > n &)] &,  (* Mike Honeychurch *)
    Cases[#, x_ /; Abs@Total@x <= n] &, (* Mike Honeychurch *)
    DeleteCases[#, x_ /; Abs@Total@x > n] &, (* Mike Honeychurch *)
    If[Abs@Total@# <= n, #, Nothing] & /@ # &, (* OkkesDulgerci *)
    If[Abs[#1 + #2] <= n, {#1, #2}, Nothing] & @@@ # & (* OkkesDulgerci *)};
results = ConstantArray[0, Length@functions];
timings = Table[First[RepeatedTiming[results[[i]] = functions[[i]]@list]],
  {i, Length@functions}];
Equal @@ results
```

> True

```
Grid[Transpose[{Prepend[functions, "function"], 
   Prepend[ timings, "timing"]}], Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
If[Abs@Total@# <= n, #, Nothing] & /@ list
If[Abs[#1 + #2] <= n, {#1, #2}, Nothing] & @@@ list
```

> {{-2, 0}, {-2, 1}, {-2, 2}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 
>     2}, {0, -2}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, -2}, 
>   {1, -1}, {1,   0}, {2, -2}, {2, -1}, {2, 0}}