# Dropping elements from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

```
list = {{1,0,x-y},{1,0,0},{0,2x,x-y}, {x-y,x,1}, {0,2x,1}, {-1,-y+x,0}, {1,y,0}, {y-x,2y,0}, {0,x+y,-x}, {1,y-2x,0},{-1,2(x+y),-1},{0,3x,0},{3x,2y,0},{0,-x-y,-1},{-x+3y,0,0},{2x-3y,0,1}, {3x,-x,1}}
```

From the list I would like to drop all the tuples which contain **any** `ax+by` where $a\geq0$, $b\geq0$, and $a$ and $b$ are not both zero at the same time.

For example, we can drop  `{x-y,x,1},{y-x,2y,0},{0,x+y,-x}`, because these contain respectively `x`, `2y`, `x+y`. But we cannot drop `{1,0,x-y},{-1,-y+x,0},{2x-3y,0,1},{0,-x-y,-1},{-x+3y,0,0}}`, because these do not contain any `ax+by` in the stated form.

After dropping, the list should have elements:

```
reducedlist={{1,0,x-y},{1,0,0},{-1,-y+x, 0},{1,y-2x,0},{0,-x-y,-1},{-x+3y,0,0},{2x-3y,0,1}}
```

Comment: I do not really understand the criterion you want to impose, or more precisely the example you give. You wrote that we can delete `{x-y,x,1}` but NOT `{1,0,x-y}`, yet both elements contain the same `x-y` for which `a=1` and `b=-1` in your notation. Have I misunderstood something? Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186157/deleting-elements-from-a-list-with-a-given-condition and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208861/remove-a-list-element-based-on-condition

Comment: Thanks for question   @– DiSp0sablE_H3r0 "The criterion is to drop any tuples which contain ANY ax+by in the form as stated. In the examples {x-y,x-1} and {1,0,x-y}, the second tuple does not contain any such ax+by (the element x-y is not in this form because b<0), but the first tuple does (the element x has a=1,b=0)."

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
coeffsNotBothZero = Not @* FreeQ[x | y]; 

coeffsNotBothNonNegative = FreeQ[{__?NonNegative}]@
   Outer[Coefficient, Select[coeffsNotBothZero] @ #, {x, y}] &;

Select[coeffsNotBothNonNegative] @ list
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, x - y}, {1, 0, 0}, {-1, x - y, 0}, {1, -2 x + y, 0}, 
>  {0, -x - y, -1}, {-x + 3 y, 0, 0}, {2 x - 3 y, 0, 1}}
> ```

You can also do:

```
coeffsNotBothNonNegative2 = FreeQ[_?Positive][
    Select[coeffsNotBothZero][#] /. {i_Integer :> Sign[i], x | y -> 1}] &;

Select[coeffsNotBothNonNegative2] @ list == Select[coeffsNotBothNonNegative] @ list
```

> True

Comment: many thanks for the  above code. How can we  adapt your code using for loop?. I think we will start like that ,but dont know the rest pointed with ???   a=Length[list]   ReducedList = ConstantArray[0., a];    For[i = 1, i <= a, i++, ??

Comment: @gunes, if you _**really have to**_ use a `For` loop, you can try: `reducedList = {};
For[i = 1, i < Length[list], i++, If[coeffsNotBothNonNegative@list[[i]], 
  AppendTo[reducedList, list[[i]]]]]; reducedList`

Answer (score 5):

We may use "DeleteCases" and a pattern like:

```
list = {{1, 0, x - y}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 2 x, x - y}, {x - y, x, 1}, {0, 
    2 x, 1}, {-1, -y + x, 0}, {1, y, 0}, {y - x, 2 y, 0}, {0, 
    x + y, -x}, {1, y - 2 x, 0}, {-1, 2 (x + y), -1}, {0, 3 x, 
    0}, {3 x, 2 y, 0}, {0, -x - y, -1}, {-x + 3 y, 0, 0}, {2 x - 3 y, 
    0, 1}, {3 x, -x, 1}};

pattern = ({___, (a_ : 1)  x + (b_ : 1)  y, ___} /; 
     a > 0 && b > 0) | ({___, (a_ : 1) x, ___} /; 
     a > 0 ) | ({___, (b_ : 1) y, ___} /; b > 0);
DeleteCases[list // Expand, pattern]
```

This gives:

```
{{1, 0, x - y}, {1, 0, 0}, {-1, x - y, 0}, {1, -2 x + y, 
  0}, {0, -x - y, -1}, {-x + 3 y, 0, 0}, {2 x - 3 y, 0, 1}}
```